# Keras: can I use model.predict but not model.predict_generator to predict if I train the model with model.fit_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am new to `keras`. Now I am going to predict test image groups with the model I trained using `model.fit_generator`. Can I use `model.predict`? Not sure how to use `model.predict_generator`. And the literature showed the results of these two are different, which one is better?

Thanks a lot!

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    enter code here`rotation_range=
    ...
    zoom_range = 0.05) 


model = Sequential()
model.add 
...


model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_x, train_y, batch_size=batch_size), 
    steps_per_epoch=train_x.shape[0] // batch_size, 
    epochs=epochs, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))


from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
test_y_hat = model.predict(test_x)
roc_auc_score(test_y, test_y_hat)
```

Comment: Better? Using what criteria?

Comment: Yes - you can use `model.predict`. What do you mean by using `fit_generator`? And what literature claims the difference between these two approaches? :)

Comment: Here is the link, not quite understood. Since they are different, I think one should be better.     Thanks!


https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-a-thing-you-should-know-about-keras-if-you-plan-to-train-a-deep-learning-model-on-a-large-fdd63ce66bd2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that
Taking a look at the [code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py) for `fit_generator()` you can see that model does not *remember* how it was trained. In fact you can use all these APIs 
(`fit`, `fit_generator`, `predict`, `predict_generator`) on a keras model in any order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just curious what the difference of predict, predict_generator

Comment: when using `predict` you need to pass all your test data at once to the function but when using `predict_generator` you pass a generator object to the function that loads data batch by batch and passes that to the model. It is useful when your data doesn't fit in ram and you can read it in small chunks for example from a file.